# Dell XPS 9575 + Ubuntu 20.04.1: Keyboard/trackpad unresponsive on boot

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, xps

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: XPS 15 9575
Kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic
BIOS version: 1.13.0
Boot-loader: grub2

After rebooting Ubuntu on my XPS-15 9575, keyboard and trackpad does not respond for about 15 seconds, and sometimes requires an entire reboot to get keyboard responsive. The touchscreen still works and the system is otherwise responsive.

Have tried:

reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all`, by using the touchscreen to open a terminal, but problem reoccurs on startup

keyboard also becomes responsive when the screen is folded back and back forward, might have something to do with the 2-in-1 nature of the laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the keyboard/trackpad working on Ubuntu 20.04.1, the workaround is to add "blacklist intel_vbtn" to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

I was able to find this link below that helped me to solve my problem. Workaround seems to be necessary for all but the latest linux kernels.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1822394

Comment: Thank You!. Worked for me on my XPS 15 9575 under Ubuntu 21.04